# Caching in Server Sent Event over distributed servers

Tags: node.js, caching, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events, distributed-system

I understand with SSE a cache is needed to keep track of subscribed clients and event IDs to keep track events that haven't been consumed by clients.

How is the caching expected to work if my server is scaled up into multiple instances with 1 load balancer at the front balancing requests?

Comment: I think you need to extract your cache as a standalone service. Then all the multiple instances connect to a single cache.